# How to set a model value from child controller to a model in parent controller in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am stuck in an application where I have a table containing input fields for entering expense_id value and amount. The amount element is bound to a custom directive where by hitting ctrl+enter will add a new tr containing empty fields.Now while submitting I am unable to calculate the total amount of all the amount fields. Here is the markup

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
                        <tr class="info" style="font-weight: bold">
                            <td>EXPENCE TYPE</td>
                            <td>AMT</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr ng-repeat="expense in expenceentry">
                            <td>
                                <!-- editable username (text with validation) --> <span
                                editable-text="expense.expensetype_id"
                                ng-model="expense.expensetype_id"
                                e-name="expense.expensetype_id" e-form="expenceentryform"
                                e-required
                                e-typeahead="expense.expensetype_id as expense.expensetype_name for expense in expensetypes.record">
                            </span>
                            </td>
                            <td ng-controller="MyCtrl">
                                <input type="number" ng-model="expense.amount" on-keyup-fn="handleKeypress">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
```

and the controller for MyCtrl is:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.keylog = [];
    $scope.keyCount= 0;
    var len;
    //$scope.expense.amount="100";
    // $scope.$parent.test=$scope.expense.amount;    

    $scope.handleKeypress = function(key) {
        $scope.keylog.push(key);
        if($scope.keylog[len-1]==17 && $scope.keylog[len]==13)
            $scope.addUser();
          len=$scope.keylog.length;
    }
}
```

Custom directive is

```
app.directive('onKeyup', function() {
return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    function applyKeyup() {
      scope.$apply(attrs.onKeyup);
    };           

    var allowedKeys = scope.$eval(attrs.keys);
    elm.bind('keyup', function(evt) {
        //if no key restriction specified, always fire
        if (!allowedKeys || allowedKeys.length == 0) {
            applyKeyup();
        } else {
            angular.forEach(allowedKeys, function(key) {
                if (key == evt.which) {
                    applyKeyup();
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

});

Parent Controller for this is :

```
function expenseEntry($scope, $filter, $http,expense_type,expenseinsert,employee) {
    $scope.total="0.00";
      $scope.deliveryboys =employee.get();



     $scope.update=function(){
        // $scope.action="Add";
       var ret=expenseinsert.save($scope.expense);
       alert("Data inserted..!!!");
    };

    $scope.expensetypes=expense_type.get();

    $scope.addUser = function() {
        $scope.inserted = {
          expensetype_id:'',
          amount: null 
        };

        $scope.expenceentry.push($scope.inserted);

      };
      $scope.expenceentry = [
        {expensetype_id: '', amount: ''}

      ];
```

};

Answer (score 0):

Your code is quite confusing because its not clear what information you actually need.

But in any case, as per the title of your post. You can access the immediate parent controller scope using

```
$scope.$parent.varName;
```

If its not the immediate parent and you don't to use $parent, you can rely on inheritance of scopes. The child scopes should have access to the parents scope unless it is declared as an isolate scope.Just watch out for using primitives instead of objects for data-binding.

Great resource for that will be [javascript-prototypal-inheritance](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes#javascript-prototypal-inheritance)